# Something like the Zero MQ REP/REQ model but without having to reply?

Tags: zeromq

## Currently I have a REP/REQ model up and running in my code.

However, I do not need for either to send replies. So replies are just wasting time.. I don't know if that matters in the real world or not.

### Basically it looks like this.

#### Client PCs - Connect - REQ

these guys all connect to the Server and update the Server with Info they have on a regular basis. They don't care if the Server didn't receive a particular message, nor do they need any info back from the Server.

there are many of these guys but not excessive.. Let's say between 10 and 100.. all hitting the same server.. well probably not, probably it will be in groups.. a group of them hit one server, another group another.. clients would send messages several times a second. But not much more than several. I have not really done any timing, I don't know how really to time on my computer at less than 1-2 ms resolution so I really don't know what to expect or what is feasible in terms of performance and how many REQ clients can be served by 1 server REP.

#### Server PC - Bind - REP

this guy sits there running in a loop on his own separate thread waiting for REQs to come in. He sends replies to the REQs because he has to, not because he really wants to or needs to.

#### Alternate Models

from some googling it seems that PUSH PULL was recommended if you just want to sent messages and don't care about replies.

However, I couldn't figure out how to fit that into my architecture because the binds and connects seem to be reversed from what I need to have.. I would like my Bind to be on the Server because the Client "Connect" guys are not always available to be reached..

### Solutions

#### 1) good alternate model

A good alternate model that works and is relatively simple would be great. I'm not sure there really is one but apart from REP/REQ and PUB/SUB I don't really know too much about other models.

#### 2) I'm worrying about nothing?

if message replies to REQ by REP are always going to be really fast and the reception of those replies by by REQ from REP also are really fast, then I guess I'm worrying about nothing. That would be good to know, so feel free to let me know if this is the case.

### The Connection question

I don't really understand what connecting sockets does.

On a client REQ should I make a connect at the start of each loop before sending that one single message? Or should I connect before the loop to my socket that I also created before the loop?

I also don't understand what this means in terms of reliability or if I have to make special checks about connected status and reconnect, or if that is done automatically.

#### To sum up

1. I have a "global" context.. created at the start, disposed of at the end
2. This daddy context has 1 or 2 sockets (connected to the same address, including port) - I'm still debugging this *dual socket on the same address* thing so I'm not sure if that is ok or it just doesn't work that way - *clarification would be nice*
3. These context(s) are lazy initialized and outside the loop scope, so we are not recreating sockets on a regular basis
4. connect calls for the sockets occur currently outside of the loop scope, but I'm not sure if it is not better to have them inside the loop scope.
5. I think I'm getting mixed up here.. I think the dual sockets are on my PUB/SUB model .. 1 PUB with 2 SUB sockets on each client, but anyhow please let me know if that would be a problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need Request-Reply, do not use it.

Request-Reply is generally slow because you need a round trip to the server for every message. This means you get twice the *network latency*, which is the time a network package needs to travel over the network. That does not matter if network traffic is low but will become a bottleneck when the traffic is high, for example multiple messages per second.

As you already mentioned Push-Pull is a valid alternative for one-way traffic. With Push-Pull you create a Pull socket on the server and bind it to an endpoint (this is similar to the Reply socket). You create a Push socket on the clients and connect it to the server endpoint (this is similar to the Request socket).

If you send multiple messages from the client to the same server, you should connect only once. Setting up a network connection is a costly operation because it requires multiple network round trips, at least for TCP.

Comment: hi, yes I use ZMQ in a few different ways.. one is REP/REQ.. but push/pull I couldn't figure out because it wanted to bind the "wrong end" for my use case (I only have a stable end on one end, so that's the one I want to bind - the end that would make REQ if it was REP/REQ model)

Comment: for my PUB/SUB... which has a different use, I have one glaring problem... PUB/SUB seems to care about getting every last message through, so SUB doesn't miss a message. But the code I'm adapting to ZeroMQ works on the principle that the latest message is the only relevant one, and sends updates frequently. So if there is any kind of hold up, messages will pile up. There seems to be some kind of last message feature in ZeroMQ but it only applies to a single envelope as far as I understand, not last message for all envelopes. Do you have any suggestions here as to what to do?

Comment: @ycomp Yes, you normally bind on the stable part of the architecture. That is normally the server. And the server often uses a REP, PUSH or PUB socket. Other setups are possible and with ZeroMQ sockets you can bind and connect on either side.

Comment: @ycomp The ZeroMQ guide describes [advanced Pub-Sub patterns](https://zguide.zeromq.org/docs/chapter5/).